# If $\exists f : (X,\tau) \rightarrow (\{ 0,1\}, \tau_\text{discr})$ continuous, non constant, $(X,\tau) $ is not connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and consider the discrete topology over $\{0,1\}$;

Prove
that if, there exists a continuous non-constant mapping $ f : X \rightarrow \{ 0,1\}$,
allora $(X, \tau)$ is not connected.

I have no idea how to tackle this, any idea?

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy I see, thanks a lot!, so these are the open sets that disconnect X

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy I don't know wy you changed what you initially wrote. I think it was right, but this one instead : (-1/2,1/2) and (1/2,2) ... where do you get those from? the only open sets in {0,1} are {0},{1},{0,1} and the empty set

Comment: $X=f^{-1}(\{0\}^{c}) \cup f^{-1}(\{1\}^{c})$ a disjoint union of two non-empty open sets if $f$ attains both  the values $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy.. what is the point of complementing ?$ \{0\}^c=\{1\}$ and $\{1\}^c=\{0\} in \{0,1\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

$X$ is connected if and only if the only both open and closed subspaces are $X$ and $\varnothing$. Try to find other open and closed subsets from these hypotheses.

Comment: would $f^{-1}(0)$ and$ f^{-1}(1)$ do the trick?

Comment: Yes, of course (you don't have many choices…).

Comment: @ Bernard what guarantees they are not empty?

Comment: Both values are attained since $f$ is supposed non-constant (there are only two possible values).